# Webpack and "@" in URL()

Tags: vue.js, webpack

`<img src='@/assets/image.jpg'>` works fine, and is translated into `/static/img/image.xxxxx.jpg`. However trying to use it in CSS like `background-image:url('@/assets/image.jpg');` does not work. It is left unchanged in the resulting html. Using Vue, but I believe it is Webpack that is doing the expansion of "@".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `<style>` tag and CSS files, URLs with aliases must be prefixed with `~`, which tells Webpack that the path is not relative to the current directory and requires path resolution. Your CSS should look like this:

```
background-image: url('~@/assets/image.jpg');
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me in the <style> section. Interestingly it did not work with style="..." on the element (not that you said it would), but the <style> tag is the right place to do it anyway.